# Control a service from another application in Vista

Tags: .net, windows-services

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a windows service in .NET and then create another windows.forms process that connects to the service and passes parameters, modifies and views its datastructures and connected database, etc.

I believe that in Vista this is only possible with the use of sockets, and not with a ServiceController class. Can anyone direct me to examples or tutorials on how to do this, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a `ServiceController` limitation, but then: I rarely use Vista ;-p

Rather than raw sockets... one option is to have the service act as a WCF host, via [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx). Your app would be a WCF client, (proxy generated via `svcutil.exe` or via the IDE). This would make it painless to talk to, The only question would be which channel to use - perhaps named pipes, since that is machine specific.